# Unknown recursive calls

Tags: c, sdl

I am trying to create a program that displays an image for roughly 2 seconds and then exits but the problem is that I get a segmentation fault at the end (the program executes fine though). The following observations tell me that the stack overflows at the call to `close()` function:

1) Valgrind says there is a stack overflow.

2) Messages in the `close()` function show up a lot of times, even before the `Loading Media...` messsage

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int init()
{
    int success = 1;

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) > 0) {
        leave("Cannot initialize SDL.");
        success = 0;
    }

    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Show an image",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    if(gWindow == NULL) {
        leave("Window could not be created.");
        success = 0;
    }

    gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(gWindow);

    return success;
}

int loadMedia() {
    int success = 1;

    gHelloWorld = SDL_LoadBMP("hello.bmp");

    if(gHelloWorld == NULL) {
        leave("Error while loading image");
        success = 0;
    }

    return success;
}

void close()
{
    printf("Releasing image...\n");
    SDL_FreeSurface(gHelloWorld);
    gHelloWorld = NULL;
    printf("Released image.\n");

    printf("Releasing Window...\n");
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    gWindow = NULL;
    printf("Released Window\n");

    printf("Shutting systems...\n");
    SDL_Quit();
    printf("Done.\n\n");

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Initializing...\n-----\n\n");
    int rc = init();
    assert(rc = 1 && "Error while initializing.");

    printf("Loading Media...\n\n");
    rc = loadMedia();
    assert(rc = 1 && "Error while loading image.");

    SDL_BlitSurface(gHelloWorld, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL);

    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(gWindow);

    SDL_Delay(2000);

    printf("-------\nclosing...\n");

    close();

    return 0;
}
```

I think I am overriding an internal function somewhere because the error doesn't show up when I change the function name or just directly insert the code instead of putting it in a seperate function but AFAIK all SDL functions begin with 'SDL_' prefix and I could not find any `close()` definition in the source code.

Valgrind output:

```
==4420== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801ff8
==4420== 
==4420== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==4420==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFE801FF8
==4420==    at 0x4E48A4A: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.1)
==4420==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==4420==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==4420==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==4420==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==4420==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==4420== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801ff0
==4420== 
==4420== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==4420==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFE801FF0
==4420==    at 0x4A256A5: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:58)
==4420==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==4420==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==4420==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==4420==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==4420==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==4420== 
==4420== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4420==     in use at exit: 272,392 bytes in 1,013 blocks
==4420==   total heap usage: 21,466 allocs, 107,735 frees, 46,031,777 bytes allocated
==4420== 
==4420== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4420==    definitely lost: 41,000 bytes in 8 blocks
==4420==    indirectly lost: 176 bytes in 4 blocks
==4420==      possibly lost: 8,211 bytes in 126 blocks
==4420==    still reachable: 223,005 bytes in 875 blocks
==4420==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4420== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==4420== 
==4420== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4420== ERROR SUMMARY: 1047384 errors from 24 contexts (suppressed: 43647 from 3)
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: `close()` is a standard c function that operates on file descriptor. It is defined in `unistd.h`. You might want to change your function to something else.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Sorry about that. Fixed it

Comment: @alvits But I am not including `unistd.h`, will it still affect the standard function ?

Comment: The include file is only for function prototyping. The function exists in the standard library that your program is compiled with. The usual behavior of the compiler is compare your function call against the function declaration. Can you compile with with `-Wall`?

Comment: @alvits yes, I already did but it doesnt show any warnings.

Comment: You might like to show us the Valgrind logging.

Comment: @alk it just says `Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801ff8` (after printing messages in `close()` many times) and then `Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)` ...

Comment: Seeing all might shed light on this.

Comment: @alk it says `Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFE801FF0 at 0x4A256A5: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:58)`. I am not sure what file is about

Comment: I should have set "**all**" bold? I do not need to ask for each single log line with a single comment, do I? Just add the whole log as an update to the end of your question.

Comment: Done. Added valgrind output at the end of the question.

Comment: I am a bit puzzled since I am not too familiar with the SDL library. But aren't gWindow and gHelloWorld, gScreenSurface just undefined in main()? I am wondering why you don't need to pass a reference around. That would certainly explain why you don't have seg faults when copying everything together.

Comment: @Drake Have you changed the name of your close() function ? As others have mentioned, bad things is bound to happen when you name your function like that. Do it. Really.

Comment: @nos I think that was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I was overriding the standard `close()` function in `unistd.h` which is probably used by SDL's internal functions. Changing the name of the function helps.